# iOS: Setting a different icon name from app name?

Tags: ios, xcode

Let's say I have an iOS app entitled "The Most Awesome iOS App".

This is the actual name of my application. It is what I want to appear in local/push notification titles, in the Settings app, etc.

However, I'd like its home screen icon to have a simpler title, like "Awesome".

As is, you'll see something on the homescreen like "The...S App". Not very useful!

If I set `CFBundleDisplayName` to "Awesome" then the homescreen icon shows the correct title, but everything else also says "Awesome". If I set `CFBundleName` to "Awesome" it has the exact same effect even if `BundleDisplayName` is not set.

I definitely do have apps on my device which have settings page names and notifications with a long title, with abbreviated home screen titles, so I'm assuming this can be done. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, just change the "product name" in build setting

Hey~ hope you already solve your case. I just ass a helpful tutorial about your case. developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1823/_index.html –

Basically the tutorial says:
Add a property named "Bundle display name" in your Info.plist of your xcode project. Then set the name you what change in the value of the "Bundle display name" Key.

I tried it. And it works for my project

Comment: This still has the unwanted effect of changing the title in both the notification center popups and the system Settings panel. However, I could swear that I've seen apps in the past that have different text on the icon versus in the settings app, but I can't find any examples at this moment so maybe it's something that iOS no longer allows...